# canvas new Image() from sprite

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have written an script to animate some images using the `canvas.js` from http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-canvas

However, because my script tries to load about 20 images on pageload it takes at least 6 seconds for it to finally run, I would like to fix this by using a sprite.

I would like to know how I can get a new `Image()` object from my sprite image (something like `new Image(xoffset, yoffset, width, height)`).

Currently I am trying this:

```
images = [];

images.push(new Image("/static/theme/lol/images/loader/sprite.jpg", 0, 0,   {  width: 180, height: 550, alpha: 1.0 } ));
images.push(new Image("/static/theme/lol/images/loader/sprite.jpg", 180, 0,  { width: 180, height: 550, alpha: 1.0 } ));
images.push(new Image("/static/theme/lol/images/loader/sprite.jpg", 360, 0,  { width: 180, height: 550, alpha: 1.0 } ));
images.push(new Image("/static/theme/lol/images/loader/sprite.jpg", 540, 0,  { width: 180, height: 550, alpha: 1.0 } ));
images.push(new Image("/static/theme/lol/images/loader/sprite.jpg", 729, 0,  { width: 180, height: 550, alpha: 1.0 } ));
images.push(new Image("/static/theme/lol/images/loader/sprite.jpg", 900, 0,  { width: 180, height: 550, alpha: 1.0 } ));
images.push(new Image("/static/theme/lol/images/loader/sprite.jpg", 1080, 0,  { width: 180, height: 550, alpha: 1.0 } ));
images.push(new Image("/static/theme/lol/images/loader/sprite.jpg", 1260, 0,  { width: 180, height: 550, alpha: 1.0 } ));
images.push(new Image("/static/theme/lol/images/loader/sprite.jpg", 1440, 0,  { width: 180, height: 550, alpha: 1.0 } ));
images.push(new Image("/static/theme/lol/images/loader/sprite.jpg", 1620, 0,  { width: 180, height: 550, alpha: 1.0 } ));
images.push(new Image("/static/theme/lol/images/loader/sprite.jpg", 1800, 0,  { width: 180, height: 550, alpha: 1.0 } ));
images.push(new Image("/static/theme/lol/images/loader/sprite.jpg", 1980, 0,  { width: 180, height: 550, alpha: 1.0 } ));
images.push(new Image("/static/theme/lol/images/loader/sprite.jpg", 2160, 0,  { width: 180, height: 550, alpha: 1.0 } ));
images.push(new Image("/static/theme/lol/images/loader/sprite.jpg", 2340, 0,  { width: 180, height: 550, alpha: 1.0 } ));
images.push(new Image("/static/theme/lol/images/loader/sprite.jpg", 2520, 0,  { width: 180, height: 550, alpha: 1.0 } ));
images.push(new Image("/static/theme/lol/images/loader/sprite.jpg", 2700, 0,  { width: 180, height: 550, alpha: 1.0 } ));
images.push(new Image("/static/theme/lol/images/loader/sprite.jpg", 2880, 0,  { width: 180, height: 550, alpha: 1.0 } ));
images.push(new Image("/static/theme/lol/images/loader/sprite.jpg", 3060, 0,  { width: 180, height: 550, alpha: 1.0 } ));
images.push(new Image("/static/theme/lol/images/loader/sprite.jpg", 3240, 0,  { width: 180, height: 550, alpha: 1.0 } ));
images.push(new Image("/static/theme/lol/images/loader/sprite.jpg", 3420, 0,  { width: 180, height: 550, alpha: 1.0 } ));
```

However, despite the [website (link)](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-canvas#image) showing that this should set the x/y coordinates of the image, when I use `console.log`(images) every image in the array still shows up as 0/0 instead of their respective values.

When I move the x/y values inside the options array (inside the new `Image()` with width/height/alpha) the entire sprite gets squeezed to the width/height defined and displayed, the x/y values do show up in the `console.log` correctly though.

I am very confused as to how this is supposed to work and hope someone can clarify this and help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to a 3rd party spritesheet cutter, canvas itself can cut sprites.

The canvas has a version of context.drawImage that will clip sprites from your spritesheet.

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/rmvQn/

**For example, if you have a simple 2-sprite spritesheet like this:**

[image]

**And you define the sprites like this:**

```
var sprites = {};
sprites["shipOff"] = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    w: 90,
    h: 90
};
sprites["shipOn"] = {
    x: 90,
    y: 0,
    w: 90,
    h: 90
};
```

**Give the sprites object a draw() method to draw any sprite by name at your desired x,y:**

```
sprites.draw=function(spritename,x,y){
    var sprite=this[spritename];
    ctx.drawImage(this.spritesheet,
        sprite.x,sprite.y,sprite.w,sprite.h,  // this clips the sprite!
        x,y,sprite.w,sprite.h
    );
}
```

**And draw any sprite like this**

```
// draw the "shipOn" sprite at canvas location 20,50

sprites.draw("shipOn", 20,50);

// draw the "shipOff" sprite at canvas location 100,50

sprites.draw("shipOff", 100,50);
```

**Or export the sprites as images like this**

```
sprites.toImage=function(spritename){
    var sprite=this[spritename];
    var tempCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
    var tempCtx=tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
    tempCanvas.width=sprite.w;
    tempCanvas.height=sprite.h;
    tempCtx.drawImage(this.spritesheet,
        sprite.x,sprite.y,sprite.w,sprite.h,
        0,0,sprite.w,sprite.h
    );
    var img=new Image();
    img.src=tempCanvas.toDataURL();
    return(img);
}
```

**Snippet:  Just define the sprites and create images from them**

```
var sprites={};
sprites["shipOff"]={x:0,y:0,w:90,h:90};
sprites["shipOn"]={x:90,y:0,w:90,h:90};
sprites.toImage=function(spritename){
    var sprite=this[spritename];
    var tempCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
    var tempCtx=tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
    tempCanvas.width=sprite.w;
    tempCanvas.height=sprite.h;
    tempCtx.drawImage(this.spritesheet,
        sprite.x,sprite.y,sprite.w,sprite.h,
        0,0,sprite.w,sprite.h
    );
    var imagename=spritename+"Image";
    sprites[spritename].image=new Image();
    sprites[spritename].image.src=tempCanvas.toDataURL();
}
sprites.spritesheet=new Image();
sprites.spritesheet.onload=start;
sprites.spritesheet.crossOrigin="anonymous";
sprites.spritesheet.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/double_ship.png";
function start(){
    sprites.toImage("shipOff");
    sprites.toImage("shipOn");

    // testing
    document.body.appendChild(sprites["shipOff"].image);
    document.body.appendChild(sprites["shipOn"].image);
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing it but it seems the library i'm using has overwritten some of the default canvas objects, unfortunatly I do need the library because I have multiple canvas elements that need individual animations and I don't know how to achieve this without the library.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.  I've added to my answer with a method which exports the sprites to image objects.  I left the animation part of my answer but you can ignore that for your purposes.

Comment: Thank you, although I am getting this error now: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

Comment: I've added just the sprite-to-image snipped to my answer.  Here's a demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/dkTn8/

Comment: the error is not because I inserted your code incorrectly, as I said earlier I think it's because the library overwrites the default canvas objects. For example, I can't even use new Image(), I need to specify the image path as a parameter or I get an error "Can't load image: undefined"

Comment: Ouch..That's a severly misbehaving library!  OK, how about cutting your sprites first (before loading the libarary) and then load the library in an image.onload property when your images are already loaded+cut?

Comment: Guess that would be the only other solution, I'll leave it unmarked as answer and give the question another 24 hour (just in case someone who has experience with the library knows a way posts an answer), if nobody else posts something better I'll mark this as the answer, thanks for helping!

Comment: I rewrote my code to work without any library, your code helps me perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that those are x and y values.

e.g.

images.push(new Image("/static/theme/lol/images/loader/sprite.jpg", **x=0**, **y=0**,   {  width: 180, height: 550, alpha: 1.0 } ));

Comment: doesn't work, x/y values in console.log are still 0/0, aside of that it suprises me it doesn't throw an syntax error in the console never knew you could define parameter names this way